# Cómo mostrar los n primeros registros de una consulta

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero traer solamente los n primeros registros  de una misma fecha con la sentencia actual solo me retorna un registro; sin embargo si se hacen 2 entradas en la misma fecha a la hora de hacer la consulta solo retorna la primera entrada, es decir la primera entrada registrada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function consultarFecha($empno,$fechainicio)

{



$res = Array("idclave"=>"","fechaEntrada"=>"","fechaSalida"=>"");



$qry = "select



            CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida,

            CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada, 

            DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS sumaHoras 

        from tblasistencia where idclave = '".$empno."' and 

            fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 00:00:00', 103) and 

            CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 23:59:59',103)";



$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn,$qry);

if( $stmt === false) {

    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() . " qry " .$qry, true) );

}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {



//  echo $row['fechaEntrada'].", ".$row['FechaSalida']."<br />";

    //$res["idclave"] =  $row['idclave'];

    $res["fechaEntrada"] = $row['fechaEntrada'];

    $res["fechaSalida"] = $row['fechaSalida'];

    $res["sumaHoras"] = $row['sumaHoras'];

}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);



return  $res;

}
```

Comment: Deberías de dar mas detalles acerca de lo que quieres hacer, ya que como formulas la pregunta quedan muchas incógnitas, es decir: quieres obtener todos los registros entre dos fechas? quieres obtener todos los registros con una fecha determinada? o que es lo que necesitas?

Comment: Si quiero obtener todos los n registros con una fecha determinada, Ejemplo: si hay dos registros de la fecha  2017-09-11, que me retorne los n registros de esa fecha y no solo un registro.

Comment: Elimina  **idclave = '".$empno."' and** de la consulta. `idclave` parece ser un PK aún que no queda claro, si filtras por el solo te devolverá ese registro

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer una consulta del tipo

```
Select * 
from tblasistencia
where fecha between fechaInicio and fechaFin
```

..donde **fechaInicio y fechaFin** son dos variables que previamente puedes preparar fechaInicio es la fecha que buscas y fechaFin es el intervalo que necesitas (por ejemplo súmale un día con la función de suma de fechas)

La consulta te devolverá todos los registros comprendidos entre las 00 h. de un día y las 00 h. del siguiente.

Comment: Pero como le sumo un día mas

Comment: $fechaFin=$fechainicio;

 $nuevafecha=strtotime ( '+1 day' , strtotime ( $fechaFin ) );
 
 $nuevafecha = date ( 'j-m-Y' , $nuevafecha );
 echo $nuevafecha; Ya sumo un día pero aun asi me muestra solo un registro

Comment: Viendo el código de arriba, se me ocurre, que después de construir la select, hagas un echo de $qry  para comprobar que efectivamente la select se ha concatenado bien.

Comment: Comprueba también que esa select funciona bien directamente en la base de datos.
Al usar los convert, podría ser que no quedara bien la cadena. Hasta dónde yo sé (SQL Server) debe quedar de la siguiente manera el where.... 
      .... WHERE fecha BETWEEN '20170911' AND '20170912'

Answer (score 0):

Si estas teniendo problemas al recuperar los datos puede ser que sea por tu formato de fechas o algo parecido, en todo caso por tratarse de una base de datos tamb deben servir los operadores >, < e = asi q una opción seria probar estos en lugar del BETWEEN. Otra opción tamb es mandar a buscar la fecha pero sin especificar el tiempo a nivel de horas, es decir busca solo el "2017-09-11"

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que debes ejecutar es la siguiente:

```
"Select * 
from tblasistencia
where fechaEntrada = '".$fechainicio."' and idclave = '".$empno."';";
```

Esa consulta te debe devolver una tabla con tres columnas:
idClave, fechaEntrada, y fechaSalida de un determinado empleado, solo te queda hacer el re-nombramiento de las columnas, eso te lo de a ti.